# finding a character in a pattern in regular expression

Tags: regex, impala

I am trying to find all occurances of equals within quotes in a string

If my input string is:

```
anything='', bob2='age=24, sex=M', dilan=24, noble1='yellow'
```

I wish to find my characters as follows

```
anything='', bob2='age=24, sex=M', dilan=24, nobel1=24
                      ^       ^
```

Followed by replacing it as

```
anything='', bob2='age~24, sex~M', dilan=24, nobel1=24
                      ^       ^
```

I tried the following to find all the occurances

```
'[^',].+?'
```

But that didnt work.

Comment: What tool/language are you using? A possible answer might be depending on it. Are your strings always well formatted (no escape sequences inside quotes)?

Comment: Language used is Hadoop Impala SQL. No escape sequences inside quotes

Comment: There will not be any quotes within the quotes. so param2='age='24', sex='M'' will never be legitimate case for this question

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the groups to do that with regex.

Try this code:

```
(?<=age)(\=)(\S+\s\w+)(\=)
```

Then, substitute the 1st and 3rd group with `~`, and keep the 2nd group intact: `~$2~`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qxR9ty/1

**Update**

You can first use Negative Lookbehind as suggested by @Maverick_Mrt, and then cancel whatever category you want to exclude by adding `|` e.g. `cat1|cat2`

```
(?<!app|policy_name|dvc_host|sender|sal)\=
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qxR9ty/

Comment: Thanks. But there is a problem, i wouldnt be able to hard code "age"

Comment: i would not be able to predict the list of parameters like app|policy_name hardcoded

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Can you predict the lists within quotes, like sex and age?

Comment: Nopes cant predict the lists inside the quotes. But within the quotes there wouldnt be any quotes

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to implement your requirement just by regex.

I'd like to iterate the String char by char to implement it.

Please check the code below. I have put the comment inside it. I'm using Java but you can utilize the algorithm inside it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = "param1='', param2='age<b>=</b>24, sex<b>=</b>M', param3=24, param4='yellow'";
        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        boolean close = true;

        /**
         * Iterate the char array
         */
        for(int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i] == '\''){

                /**
                 * Ignore the escaped ' char in ''
                 */
                if(i > 0 && arr[i - 1] == '\\'){
                    break;
                }

                /**
                 * Use close to check whether equal sign is inside the ''
                 */
                if(close){
                    close = false;
                }else{
                    close = true;
                }
            }else if(arr[i] == '='){
                if(!close){
                    arr[i] = '~';
                }
            }

            System.out.print(arr[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more specific. The language used is Impala SQL,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<!param[\d+])=
```

And replace by this:

~

Breakdown:
it will look for any '=' and will see if that precedes by param[\d+] or not..
if not preceded by param\d+ then it will capture the = sign.

That = will be replaced by ~

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/FGtzrN/4)

Comment: Thanks that is almost close. I should have been more specific The actual string can be like this  app='', policy_name='age=24, sex=M, sal=300', dvc_host=24, sender='<yellow@gmail.com>'. So i cannot hardcode "param".